# Outdoor porch light wiring

Tags: electrical, outdoor

Neighbor had his father in law installed a new porch, now the outside garage lights changed. He has no power in garage unless he turns porch light on.

The box for the porch light has 2 Black, 2 White and 1 Red wire in it.  I checked the wires, no power to blacks or the red unless switch inside is turned on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What could be the problem?

Comment: The electricians here will be able to help you best if you edit your post and add photos of the wiring in the switch and light boxes. But it sounds to this novice like the switch might have had a wire connected to hot that goes on to power more of the circuit, and it is now connected to switched hot instead of hot

Comment: Obviously, when the porch was built the wiring for the light was altered somehow. Did this occur only at the light or was the switch box fiddled with as well?

Comment: We would need a bit more info it sounds like the feed to the garage was cut and the porch light added so now the switch for the porch is controlling the garage. The power for the garage will need to be moved to the other side of the switch. Not knowing how it was wired originally or now things could be made worse by guessing.

Comment: From what I understand is everything worked well before he changed the light fixtures, now there is no power to garage without switch in ON position

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the switch boxes involved as well please?